# Table view cell label get changed after scrolling and get wrong value in it how to solve it?

Tags: ios, swift3

**every time I scroll up or down value get changed with wrong value at 1st it shows correct value but after scrolling it get changed every time.**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    //creating a cell using the custom class
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ShowPercentageAttandanceTableViewCell




    cell.rollNo.text = String(describing: self.mainArrayRoll[indexPath.row])


        var location = Int()

        for item in self.rollPercentage {
            if item.rollCall == indexPath.row {
                location = item.absentCount  
                cell.percentage.text=String(location)
                }

            else if cell.percentage.text==("Label")
            {

                cell.percentage.text=String("0")
            }

    }


    return cell
    }
```

Here is the code.

**[![Here in image 2 label is having text =2 and gray color label is having text 0 but it automatically get change after scroll as shown in image 2[![image 2 label changes after scroll but it is showing wrong][2]][2]**

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't have a `for` loop in `cellForRow(at:)`; you should access your table's data from an array, indexed by `indexPath.row`

Comment: Classic cell reuse issue.  You aren't setting `cell.percentage.text` in some cases for reused cells because your `else` clause is checking to see if it is `"Label"` which will only be true for a fresh cell.  Try `else { cell.percentage.text = "0" }`.

Comment: @vacawama I tried what you said but it shows all labels as 0 . I don't know why.

Comment: I see the issue and provided an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are failing to set the `cell.percentage.text` to `"0"` when you didn't find the value you were looking for *and* you had a reused cell.

Try this:

```
if let item = self.rollPercentage.first(where: { $0.rollCall == indexPath.row }) {
    location = item.absentCount  
    cell.percentage.text = String(location)
} else {
    cell.percentage.text = "0"
}
```

Comment: @ vacawama brother !!! You know this was awesome.  Actually I can't tell you in words how valuable this solution for me. You are just Aaawwwsome. Thank you so much bro!!